# How to print specific string from a sentence using awk

Tags: awk

I have the following sentence within a file

```
FQDN=joe.blogs.com.
```

How can I print the string "joe"

I have tried using -->> `awk -F"=" '{print $2}' file`
but this returns joe.blogs.com as "=" is the delimiter.

Is it possible to use 2 delimiters on the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use regular expression as `FS`. Let `file.txt` content be

```
FQDN=joe.blogs.com.
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[=.]"}{print $2}' file.txt
```

output

```
joe
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are ok with `sed`, could you please try following.

```
sed 's/.*=\([^.]*\)\..*/\1/' Input_file
```

With GNU `grep` and using its `-oP` flag we could try following too.

```
grep -oP '(.*=)\K([^.]*)' Input_file
```

Comment: Beat me to this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=FQDN=)[^.]+' file
   
                      ^ all characters up to a '.'
             ^ lookbehind for 'FQDN='
      ^ only print match and Perl style regex
```

Or with Perl:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /(?<=FQDN=)([^.]+)/' file
```

With `awk` I would probably do:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS="[.=]"}  /FQDN=/{print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

why not keeping it simple and pipe awk?

```
awk -F"=" '{print $2}' | awk -F"." '{print $1}'
```

> can I use two field delimiters on one line?

No. You may do further string manipulation as post processing, or you could use a regex as field delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use awk's split function:

```
awk -F= '{ split($2,map,".");print map[1] }' file
```

Split the second = separated field into the array map using "." as the delimiter. Print the first index of the array.